# OneHotEncoder TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('float64'), dtype('O'))

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am totally new to scikit learn and pandas. I have the following code:

```
cols = ['delay', 'month', 'day', 'dow', 'hour', 'distance', 'carrier', 'dest','year','origin','arr']

tp = read_csv('D:/CCP DS Nov 2014/smartfly/smartfly_historic_train.csv', iterator=True,  chunksize=1000) 
data_2007 = concat(tp, ignore_index=True) # df is DataFrame. If error do list(tp)
data_2007.columns = ['delay', 'month', 'day', 'dow', 'hour', 'distance', 'carrier',  'dest','year','origin','arr']
data_2007 = data_2007.dropna(subset=['delay'])
tp = read_csv('D:/CCP DS Nov 2014/smartfly/smartfly_historic_test.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=1000) 
categ = [cols.index(x) for x in ['month','day','dow','hour','distance','carrier','dest']]
enc = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = categ,sparse=True)
df = data_2007.drop('delay', axis=1)
df['carrier'] = pd.factorize(df['carrier'])[0]
df['dest'] = pd.factorize(df['dest'])[0]
train_x = enc.fit_transform(df)
```

A sample record in `smartfly_historic_train.csv` looks as follows

```
-5,8,11,7,10,361,US,CLT,2013,BWI,1132
```

I am trying to convert categorical variables like `US` and `CLT` into integers so as to feed `RandomForest`, but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('float64'), dtype('O')
```

Stack Trace of error:

```
File "D:\Meerkat\meerkat\ml_new1.py", line 58, in run_from_command_line
 train_x = enc.fit_transform(df)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 1054, in fit_transform
 self.categorical_features, copy=True)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py", line 897, in _transform_selected
  return sparse.hstack((X_sel, X_not_sel))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py", line 453, in hstack
  return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py", line 583, in bmat
    dtype = upcast(*tuple([A.dtype for A in blocks[block_mask]]))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\sputils.py", line 62, in upcast
    raise TypeError('no supported conversion for types: %r' % (args,))
TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('float64'), dtype('O'))
```

Comment: Please consider editing the stacktrace of the error into your question.

Comment: I am trying to run the code from here.http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ofermend/IPython-notebooks/blob/master/blog-part-1.ipynb . Piece of code marked as In[13]

Comment: little bit of a guess here since I don't have experience with OneHotEncoder but I'm thinking it doesn't like you trying to convert distance (most likely a continuous variable) to a categorical variable.